# Optional Martingale Stopping Theorem and Brownian Motion Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I do not understand how to demonstrate that the MST holds in the following situation:

There is a Brownian Motion process $\{B(t)\}$ for $t > 0$ and stopping time defined as $T:= inf\{t : B(t) = -a \ $or$ \ b\}$. Suppose $B(0)=0$.

At time $T$, I know that $B(T)$ is either $-a$ or $b$. However, I do not know how to get $P(B(T)=-a)$ and $P(B(T)=-b)$ so as to get $E[T]$ without the MST. An intuitive response would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B_T$ takes only the values $-a$ and $b$, we have $$B_T = -a 1_{\{B_T=-a\}} + b 1_{\{B_T=b\}}.$$ Using that $\mathbb{E}(B_T)=0$ we get $$0 = \mathbb{E}(B_T)= -a \mathbb{P}(B_T=-a) + b \mathbb{P}(B_T=b). \tag{1}$$ On the other hand, we know that $$\mathbb{P}(B_T=-a) + \mathbb{P}(B_T=b) = 1. \tag{2}$$ Solving this system of linear equations allows you to compute $\mathbb{P}(B_T=-a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B_T=b)$.

In order to calculate $\mathbb{E}(T)$ you have to use that $(B_t^2-t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale and apply the optional stopping theorem.

Comment: Though I appreciate the response, my goal is to demonstrate that the optional stopping theorem holds. You applied the theorem to get your equation 1; I would like to get the result without using the theorem.

Comment: @grahmW Your comment leaves me confused; I thought you had already shown that $\mathbb{E}(B_T)=0$...? That's how I understood what you wrote. What exactly do you mean by "demonstrate that the OST holds"...? To get $(1)$ you have to apply OST to the bounded stopping time $t \wedge T$ and then let $t \to \infty$ in $\mathbb{E}(B_{T \wedge t})=0$ to conclude that $\mathbb{E}(B_T)=0$.

Comment: @grahmW See also this answer for some more details: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2565014/36150

Comment: This is only my second question posted to this site so I apologize for not being clear. My question is how do we get the result that you provided without using the OST, using only the Markov, Martingale, and other intrinsic properties of the process. Is this even possible or do we have to apply OST?

Comment: @grahmW Well, the OST is a direct consequence of the martingale property... obviously, you can "reprove" the OST for the particular stopping time we are conidering by just using the "standard" martingale property, but I don't see the point of this.

Comment: Thank you; I understand it better now.