# Expected value and variance of a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B = \{B(t) : t \ge 0\}$ be a Brownian motion and $\sigma_a$ be a the stopping time such that $\sigma_a = \inf\{t \ge 0: B(t) \le t - a\}$ for $a>0$. I want to find $\mathbb{E}[\sigma_a]$ and $\text{Var}[\sigma_a]$ but I really have no idea where to start. Could one of you give me a hint?

Comment: Try to use the Girsanov theorem or Cameron Martin formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B$ is a martingale, you can apply Doob's optional stopping theorem to get:
$$E B_{\sigma_a} = E B_0 = 0$$
Since $B_{\sigma_a} = \sigma_a - a$ almost surely, that gives you an equation to solve for $E \sigma_a$.  Applying the same technique to the martingale $B_t^2-t$ gives you an equation for the second moment.

This leaves out a few important details.  Most versions of the OST won't apply directly, but will need a sequence stopping times (e.g.,
$\sigma^M_a=\{t\geq0 : B(t)\not\in(t-a,M)\}$), and you'll need to prove both something about $\sigma_a$ (e.g., that it's almost surely finite) and apply the dominated convergence theorem.  See the outline [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564978/expectation-of-the-minimum-of-two-first-passage-times-of-a-standard-brownian-mot/2565014#2565014) for a detailed outline for a similar problem.